# Mobile Push Badge Count

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I am getting issues with Badge count on IOS. When I send the push notification via ET, I can see the badge count on IOS.

However, when I push it via API, the badge count shows up but has following issues.

Let's start with badge count 2, and once I open the notification, it becomes zero. Then again when I push the message, it becomes three, which is not right as it should become 1.

I am just wondering why the badge count is not getting updated correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badge count is maintained by the MarketingCloud server's knowledge of what it last sent to the device. To effectively reconcile the server's value with what the current device value is, use ETPush's methods to reset the badge and then update the MarketingCloud registration for that user/device:

To quote the current documentation (ETPush.h)

> /** Reset the application's badge number to zero (aka, remove it).
>   Call updateET to refresh the server with the current badge number.
>   Note: updateET may not be fully processed by the server for a number
>   of minutes; the server's badge value may be out of sync with the app
>   for a short amount of time.
>   */

`-(void)resetBadgeCount;`

`-(void)updateET;`

You'd want to follow a call to resetBadgeCount with the call to updateET which will ensure that the Marketing Cloud server (the push system's source of badge truth) reflects the state of the device.

Brian Criscuolo

Salesforce

Comment: Hi Brian 

This still seems not to work. I have made the following changes in IOS codebase.

        /**UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        ETPush.pushManager()?.resetBadgeCount()
        ETPush.pushManager()?.updateET()*/

From the server end, we were passing badge count as +1. The result was same.

We send 2 notifications from the server the badge count of the application was 2. Opened 1 of them, badge count became 0 perfect.
Now after 1 hr we sent 1 more notification, application badge count was 3. It should be 1.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Brian - Seems like we were using the  SDK version 4.8.5. We will be upgrading it and then will share the test results. Thanks